# Javascript video player prev next button not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

When clicking play next video in playlist player opens one video backward then on second click video goes forward as wanted. Same happens when clicking on play previous video...

```
<script>
let index = 0
video = document.getElementsByTagName('v')[0]
play = () => {
  const files = document.getElementById('f').files

for (var index = 0; index < files.length; index++)

{
  document.getElementById("playingName").innerHTML = files[0].name
  document.getElementById("playingNr").innerHTML = files.length/files.length
}
 
  const file = files[index++ % files.length]
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
  video.src = url
  video.load()
  
}
next = () => {
  const files = document.getElementById('f').files
   document.getElementById("playingName").innerHTML = files[((index)) % files.length].name
  document.getElementById("playingNr").innerHTML = index+1
  const file = files[index++ % files.length]
    if (index >= files.length) { index = 0; }
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
  video.src = url
  video.load()
}
prev = () => {
  const files = document.getElementById('f').files
   document.getElementById("playingName").innerHTML = files[((index)) % files.length].name
  document.getElementById("playingNr").innerHTML = index+1
  const file = files[index-- % files.length]
    if (index <= 0) { index = 0; }
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
  video.src = url
  video.load()
}

video.addEventListener('ended', play, false)
video.addEventListener('ended', next, false)
video.addEventListener('ended', prev, false)

</script>
```

When clicking play next video in playlist player opens one video backward then on second click video goes forward as wanted. Same happens when clicking on play previous video...

Comment: When clicking on prev button player opens the video one video forward then on second click player goes back to previous file in playlist as wanted...

Comment: If you want help debugging something, please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably as a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2518285).

Comment: Here is working example on the website address
https://www.rx-studio.si/playlist/list/index.html

I'd really be soooo thankull if you could please help me solving this... :)